# Arch. Screen view compressed. Stripes from top to bottom

Tags: arch-linux

After last update and upgrade i got screen view with artifacts. Now screen view compressed in SDDM and after login in KDE.I can run some app, but some not. In sddm mode can see mouse coursor.
[image]

[image]
Video cards work properly (tested in windows)

UPD:
Laptop Dell inspiron 7520
I7-3632QM/radeon 7730M
I using build-in video in i7 for boot and majority application
[image]

---

**Problem fixed :**

In Xorg.log found

```
EE) AIGLX error: dlopen of /usr/lib/dri/i965_dri.so failed, cannot open shares object file (no such file or directory). (EE) AIGLX error: unable to load driver i965 .
```

Reinstall xf86-video-fbdev and lib32-mesa-amber. -> work perfectly -> return back lib32-mesa - all ok.

Comment: uh that looks like a display driver bug. What is your graphics hardware?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and give us your hardware details. What graphics card? What driver (see `inxi -G`)? Is this a laptop or a desktop?

Comment: Update my question

Comment: Fixed. In Xorg.log fund EE) AIGLX error: dlopen of /usr/lib/dri/i965_dri.so failed, cannot open shares object file (no such file or directory). (EE) AIGLX error: unable to load driver i965 . Reinstall xf86-video-fbdev and lib32-mesa-amber. -> work perfectly -> return back lib32-mesa - all ok.

Comment: @xrk : I updated your question taking into account your last comment. Please, feel free to answer your own question and delete my edit.